# What is the best way I can compress a number that has 540,000 digits?

Tags: numbers, compression

I have a number that has about 540,000 digits and I want to compress this number to a reasonable length since 540,000 is kinda absurd. What would be the best compression algorithm for this and how small can I compress it to?

A little background: Basically I have a picture that is 200 pixels wide and 300 pixels long. I'm taking out the red green blue values of each pixel. So each pixel is represented with 9 digits (because each red green value is represented with a number between 0 - 255). The picture has 60000 pixels in total. So representing this picture as a number would equate to a number equal to 9 x 60000 = 540,000.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a number. That's an image. There are many ways to compress an image. For lossless compression, look at PNG, JPEG-2000, and BCIF.

Comment: The thing is that I want to pull up the image by typing an identifier in my program. So ideally I would want to have a program where I can open it, type in a short identifier string such as "sahSHS#@2211fSAA21113" and with that the program will be able to generate the pixel arrangements/color for the image I want. Nothing is saved memory with this program. It simply takes the character sequence you give it and uses that to determine what pixels should be shown in what location.

Comment: Sorry, you're not going to be able to compress 180,000 bytes down to 16 bytes and be able to reproduce any sort of recognizable image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't gain anything converting an image into a number. The entropy level is the same and any good compression algorithm (lossless) would perform the same, irrespective of the encoding you use

Answer (score 0):

If you want a textual version of the image as opposed to a binary format, consider encoding it in Base64 rather than Base10. This'll have each pixel be represented with 4 characters rather than 9

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Further compression should be done by encoding the image as a PNG & then taking the base64 representation of that